# How do you join multiple foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a blog using PHP and SQL, I am trying to query everything in 1 SQL query so I can bring out all of the comments with the authors and all of the blogs with the authors. Each of them have the `user.uuid` as a foreign key.

My Blog Table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `blogs` (
  `uuid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `detail` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My Blog Comments Table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `blogs_comments` (
  `uuid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `blog_uuid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_uuid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My User Table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uuid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `foreName` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `surName` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `is_admin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Here is my current SQL:

```
SELECT
b.uuid AS 'Blog ID', b.title AS 'Blog Title', b.detail AS 'Blog Body', u.uuid AS 'Blog Author ID', u.username AS 'Blog Author Username',
(SELECT bc.comment WHERE u.uuid = bc.user_uuid) AS 'Comment',
(SELECT u.uuid WHERE u.uuid = bc.user_uuid) AS 'Comment Author ID',
(SELECT u.username WHERE u.uuid = bc.user_uuid) AS 'Comment Author Username' 
FROM blogs b
INNER JOIN blogs_comments bc ON b.uuid = bc.blog_uuid
INNER JOIN users u ON b.user_id = u.uuid
```

The query is working fine, however, it has an unexpected output and looks like this:

[image]

I would like the output to have all of the comments for the comment author in 1 row, then each row will be specific to the comment author. IE:

```
Comment Author    Comment        Comment
Jaquarh           TEST           Lorem Ipsum
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to know how many comments you'll have every time, but if you do, a pivot may give you what you need. I'm a little confused about your query structure, but I think it may look something like this with a pivot:

```
SELECT
blog_id AS 'Blog ID',
title AS 'Blog Title',
detail AS 'Blog Body',
blog_author_id AS 'Blog Author ID',
username AS 'Blog Author Username',
Comment_Author_ID AS 'Comment Author ID',
Comment_Author_Username AS 'Comment Author Username',
[0] AS 'Comment 1', 
[1] AS 'Comment 2', 
[2] AS 'Comment 3', 
[3] AS 'Comment 4', 
[4] AS 'Comment 5', 
[5] AS 'Comment 6'

FROM
  (SELECT --A1
  b.uuid as blog_id, b.title, b.detail, u.uuid as blog_author_id, u.username, 
  (SELECT bc.comment WHERE u.uuid = bc.user_uuid) AS Comment,
  (SELECT u.uuid WHERE u.uuid = bc.user_uuid) AS Comment_Author_ID,
  (SELECT u.username WHERE u.uuid = bc.user_uuid) AS Comment_Author_Username,
  row_number() over(partition by b.uuid order by bc.comment) AS row_num
  FROM blogs b
  INNER JOIN blogs_comments bc ON b.uuid = bc.blog_uuid 
  INNER JOIN users u ON b.user_id = u.uuid AND u.uuid = bc.user_uuid
  ) as A1
PIVOT
(max([comment]) FOR row_num in ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5])) AS pvt
```

This article might help you too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017